# Object of class Foo could not be converted to string in PHP

Tags: php, string, type-conversion

Is there a **general** solution that I can convert anything arrays and objects to a string, not simple types only?

Like (but only as sample!)

```
$myVar1 = (string) $myInt;
$myVar2 = (string) $myArray;
```

Comment: Did you try `serialize()`?

Comment: May I ask; why would you want this?

Comment: I thought in a more generalized way, it would be more practical.

Comment: @Frunk For code insight, debugging etc..., improve code reading.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own functions, for doing exactly what you want, for example, to convert from array to string, you can use this function : `implode(', ', $array);` this function will return a string by joining all the array elemenets with this seperator ','. 
To convert an object to a string you can also write your own methode (toString() like in java for example)

```
class User {
    private $name;
    private $age;

    public function toString() {
        return $this->name . ' ' . $this->age;
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 for the good answer, but I thought of "build-in" functionality, if any!

Comment: try with var_dump($mixedVar) or print_r($mixedVar, TRUE|FALSE). with FALSE argument the result will be printed automatically to the standards output, with TRUE argument, the print_r function will return a string